# Importing a dependency within vscode extension is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to use memoize-one package https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoize-one

I've npm installed it and see it inside my node_modules but when I try to import it vscode is pointing to the correct folder and file but it's returning undefined.

I also tried importing another library lodash but still getting undefined with it as well.

in my extension.ts

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import memoizeOne from 'memoize-one';

console.log(_);
console.log(memoizeOne);
```

in my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "memoize-one": "^5.1.1"
  }
```

Comment: how you are running / executing the code . also share the error you are getting.

Comment: no error just console logging returns undefined. i run it using the debug task to run the extension